# Backend option for a html/css web app

Tags: ajax, ipad, web-applications, content-management-system, backend

This is my first post here and by the quality of answers I am used to see from this community, I hope one of you could help me on this...

I am currently working on a iPad web app based on a tutorial from lynda.com.(http://goo.gl/Hpvaa)
Basically, the app Is self contained on a single page and loads the content dynamically via Ajax from several HTML files.(otherwise the app will open in safari when a link is clicked instead of staying "native" using the add to home screen feature of iOS.
Everything works as expected but instead of using HTML files for the content, I'd like to use some sort of CMS so updates can be done by a non coder.
Now I am looking at CMSs that can output to a flat HTML file, but it is very limited and doesn't allow for custom fields or precise setup.

So my question is what would be the best CMS or other backend solution to Be able to update the content via a web based admin panel.
I am (obviously) not a very experienced programmer so the easiest is better.
Thanks in advance to all you great coders and dev...